# Hibernate aliasToBean is not working

Tags: hibernate, detachedcriteria

I have a class called "AppModel" and a query in DetachedCriteria.

My colleague and I didn't find the reason of why it is not working. Did I miss some important code or make a mistake?

Here's my class:

```
public class AppModel {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String icon;
    private String rating;
    private int downloads;

    public AppModel() {
    }

    public AppModel(Long id, String name, String type, String icon, Integer downloads) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.icon = icon;
        if (downloads != null) {
            this.downloads = downloads;
        } else {
            this.downloads = 0;
        }

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public String getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(String rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public Integer getDownloads() {
        return downloads;
    }

    public void setDownloads(Integer downloads) {
        if (downloads == null) {
            this.downloads = 0;
        } else {
            this.downloads = downloads;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.equals(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.hashCode();
    }

}
```

The Query in DetachedCriteria is like this:

```
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(AppCurrentVersion.class);
        dc.createAlias("appInfo", "_appInfo");
        dc.createAlias("_appInfo.appMetadata", "_appMetadata");
        dc.createAlias("_appMetadata.primaryCate", "_appCategory");

        dc.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                .add(Projections.groupProperty("_appInfo.id"), "id")
                .add(Projections.property("_appInfo.appName"), "name")
                .add(Projections.property("_appCategory.name"), "type")
                .add(Projections.property("_appInfo.appIcon"), "icon")
                .add(Projections.sum("downloads"), "downloads")
                );

        dc.add(Restrictions.eq("publishFlag", new Boolean(true)));
        dc.addOrder(Order.desc("downloads"));

        dc.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(AppModel.class));

        List<AppModel> list = findByCriteria(dc, sizePerPage, index);
```

The hibernate query is as below:

```
Hibernate: select appinfo1_.id as y0_, appinfo1_.app_name as y1_, appcatego3_.name as y2_, appinfo1_.app_icon as y3_, sum(this_.downloads) as y4_ from app_current_version this_ inner join app_info appinfo1_ on this_.app_info_id=appinfo1_.id inner join app_metadata appmetada2_ on appinfo1_.id=appmetada2_.app_info_id inner join app_category appcatego3_ on appmetada2_.primary_cate_id=appcatego3_.id where this_.publish_flag=? group by appinfo1_.id order by y4_ desc limit ?
```

The error message printed as :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.borneo.vo.AppModel cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
    at org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache.put(StandardQueryCache.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.putResultInQueryCache(Loader.java:2212)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listUsingQueryCache(Loader.java:2163)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2121)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1597)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:306)
    at com.borneo.framework.base.dao.BaseDAOImpl.findByCriteria(BaseDAOImpl.java:224)
    at com.borneo.framework.base.dao.BaseDAOImpl.findByCriteria(BaseDAOImpl.java:193)
    at com.borneo.dao.AppCurrentVersionDAOImpl.getMostDownloadAppsList(AppCurrentVersionDAOImpl.java:221)
    at com.borneo.rest.portal.service.AppListApiServiceImpl.getMostDownloadAppsList(AppListApiServiceImpl.java:203)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1659.getMostDownloadAppsList(Unknown Source)
    at com.borneo.rest.portal.api.WebMobilePortalAPI.getTopMostDownloadedApp(WebMobilePortalAPI.java:275)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:421)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:409)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:774)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Comment: I think `sum(this_.downloads) as y4_` causing issue. Try removing `.add(Projections.sum("downloads"), "downloads")`

Comment: It doesn't work even I remove .add(Projections.sum("downloads"), "downloads") , as well as from AppModel class.

Giving me same error.